# How do I add text to a ScrollView at run time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, text, scrollview

I would like to know how to add text to a scroll view at run time.  I am working in Android Studio.  I have a file that I am reading from and have put the lines of text into a StringBuilder buffer object.

Now how do I display the text in my ScrollView? Do I need to use .AddView?

Answer (score 2):

[Scrollview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) is a single-element container, meaning you should only have one element in it.

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

So you should add a LinearLayout in your ScrollView and add views to that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add TexView inside ScrollView:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Your string");

scrollView.addView(tv);
```

Comment: this needs to be done from the UI thread though. So put this into a runnable or something call the according method.